# App behaviour when an iOS device is restarted(with the app running)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am facing a weird problem. My iPhone app is password protected and only after entering the correct password, can the user be logged in again. Also the app has multiple screens.

Suppose I am on a particular screen(after logging in) and switch off the device(with app still running), switch on the device back and launch my application, it starts back from the screen which was visible when the device was restarted. The password screen is not shown, and it seems like applicationDidFinishLaunching was never called. When I kill the app from background and start it again, it works normal.

Wouldn't the app loose all data in memory when the device is restarted? Wouldn't the views will have to be drawn again? How exactly does an app behave in this case.

**EDIT:**
I did what TriPhoenix has suggested. What I observed is that if you switch on the device and launch the application very soon, the applicationDidBecomeActive delegate method doesn't get called. However if you give it some time before launching, everything seems to work as expected. Isn't the applicationDidBecomeActive method supposed to be called with every app launch?

What I am testing on:
OS: iOS 5.0.1
Xcode: 4.2.1
Device: iPhone 4s

Comment: Are you *sure* you're turning off the device and not just turning the screen off and on? That sounds mad if you are seeing that after a proper reboot of the device.

Comment: yes I am switching off the device("slide to power off") and yes it is definitely mad!! :(

Comment: Have you tried a 'hard' reset (holding down both buttons until it restarts)?

Comment: wouldn't that reset my device?

Comment: That is simply akin to holding the power button on a computer for ~8 seconds to power it off without a proper shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your app is very small in terms of memory usage? I remember a WWDC talk (cannot find the right one right now unfortunaly) where it is told that very small apps in terms of memory usage (a limit is not publicly defined but I think it was around 16 MiB memory usage) are not killed on low memory conditions but rather suspended to the phone's flash memory to be awakened later. I'm not sure if this is designed to survive a complete shutdown but it would sure be one of the few possibilities. To check this you could try to artificially increase your memory usage by creating some large objects / arrays and see if the problem disappears.

In any case there might be better functions to reactivate the password protection, e.g. `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` as this should cover all possibilities where the user might return to your app.

Comment: My app is actually quite bulky(over 30 MB IPA). The problem with app delegate methods is that I can't put a breakpoint on them and check it, since the device is being shutdown.

Comment: You could create a file on the device with the current date or something like that to check if and when those methdos are called.